# Anaconda Navigator shows me old versions of packages

Tags: anaconda

I upgraded by pip some packages for example

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

and new version is 2.2.0

but on Anaconda in the some env shows me still 2.0.0

if I use

```
pip list
```

shows me 2.2.0

How to upgrade in Anaconda versions of instaled packages?

Answer (score 0):

I made the experience of a hazardous journey when mixing up pip and conda package installations, therefore I do not recommend using pip - Try to install everything ALWAYS and ONLY with `conda install`. You will also find typical Python libraries via that commando. If there is any special package to be installed, e.g. local ones not published, then kindly refer to the Anaconda documentation: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

In a nutshell, my answer is to setup a brand new conda environment (also the base, so fresh grounds), install all standard packages via `conda install` and then try to install the special ones (if you have any). After that, conda update will do the magic for you very easily.